# Android App force closes, found java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: android, debugging

I built an android app that casts a spinner to a switch, to enable the user to select an operator for a calculation and see the result.

It is from the Android Boot Camp lessons. I was unhappy to find my app had no compile errors but crashed on start-up. I was watching the logcat as I ran the application and found the nullpointer exception to be on line 40. Where I pull the spinner's selection to a string variable.

```
 //spinner
    op3  = operation.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

I dumped the contents of my logcat to a text file. Here is what I think is relevant.

```
09-30 22:26:58.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1565): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 22:26:58.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1565): Process: com.schmop.flashmath, PID: 1565
09-30 22:26:58.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1565): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.schmop.flashmath/com.schmop.flashmath.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

and

**09-30 22:26:58.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1565): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-30 22:26:58.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at** com.schmop.flashmath.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
09-30 22:26:58.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
09-30 22:26:58.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-30 22:26:58.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
09-30 22:26:58.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1565):     ... 11 more
```

Here is the contents of my mainActivity in

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

int number1;
int number2;
int result;
int op1;
int op2;
String op3 = null;
int calculator;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText first = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num);
    final EditText second = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2);
    final Spinner operation = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.operator);
    final Button equals = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

    operation.setSelection(0);

    //spinner
    op3  = operation.getSelectedItem().toString();

    //start logic
    //onclick listener
    equals.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //gettext
            number1 = Integer.parseInt(first.getText().toString());
            number2 = Integer.parseInt(second.getText().toString());

            if(number1 < 21 && number1 > 0 && number2 < 21 && number2 > 0) {
            //switch
                switch(calculator) {
                case 1: op3 = "+";
                    calculator = number1 + number2;
                    break;
                case 2: op3 = "-";
                    calculator = number1 - number2;
                    break;
                case 3: op3 = "x";
                    calculator = number1 * number2;
                    break;      
                }
            } else {
                t.setText("Error: One of your Numbers is out of Range");
                }

            t.setText(number1 + op3 + number2 + "=" + calculator);


        }
    });
  //end logic
}
```

> Since it was calling a null variable, I tried adding junk data into the declaration of op3 as an attempt to fix my problem. This proved unsuccessful. I've seen some examples being solved by adding a check for null in an if statement, however I dont think it would apply here.

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation for `getSelectedItem()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItem()):

> Returns The data corresponding to the currently selected item, or null if there is nothing selected.

When the app is starting up, nothing is yet selected. Move the

```
op3  = operation.getSelectedItem()
```

inside the `onClick()` and check for `!= null` before trying to call `toString()` on the result.

Comment: I moved it behind the onclick() this morning. It worked, however still force closed. I found the nullpointerexception was because I didn't declare android:entries in the .xml for the spinner.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set any contents for the spinner, so `operation.getSelectedItem()` is returning `null`. The NPE is from trying to then call `toString()`. Populate your spinner first before trying to access items, or at least put a null check when you try to retrieve an item.